# Auto-complementary in Membership Form, slow

Tags: php, mysql

Automatic membership in the form of complementary works late. Database on the slow side. Is there a way to speed up this? User does not matter.. How do I stop to write other than the automatic complementary?(Automatic complementary; city-input. membership form is located.)

Register.php

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $().ready(function() {
 $("#sehir").autocomplete("CityAutoComp.php", {
    width: 312,
    matchContains: true,
    mustMatch: true,
    //minChars: 0,
    //multiple: true,
    //highlight: false,
    //multipleSeparator: ",",
    autofill:true,
    selectFirst: false
 });
 });
 </script>
```

CityAutoComp.php

```
 <?php 
 session_start();
 ob_start();

 $con = mysql_connect("localhost","******","****");
 if (!$con)
   {
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }
 mysql_select_db("*****", $con);
 $q = strtolower($_GET["q"]);
 if (!$q) return;

 $sql = "select DISTINCT city from location where city LIKE '%$q%'";
 $rsd = mysql_query($sql);
 while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($rsd)) {
 $cname = $rs['city'];
 echo "$cname|$\n";
 }
 ?>

 ---
 <tr>
 <th>City:</th>
 <td><input id="sehir" autocomplete="off" name="sehir" type="text" style="text-transform:      capitalize" class="inputbox" size="45" value="<?php echo post('sehir');?>" /></td>
 </tr>
```

Respects.
(I apologize for my English.)

Comment: I'll assume you mean autocomplete working slowly. If you want help with the database side, we'll need a bit more then 'it works slow'. Like, show queries and table structures and, you know, anything.

Comment: Try caching mysql data into several php files. @Naltharial I guess he's not using his own implementation but just has slow/overloaded mysql server.

Comment: Thank you for helping, Can I block writing except input from auto complete text?

Comment: @Vyktor Well yes, but there's not really much to do if he doesn't say what he's using, how, or give any information at all. If there's really nothing to do code-side or DB-side, the problems are probably more deeply rooted then just the autocomplete and he might start pondering the use of something like memcached.

Comment: Language issues aside, you should improve your question and show some code so it's more clear what your issue is.

Comment: @Editor block writing from what? Autocomplete shouldn't be writing. If your DB has so much write load all the time that not even a simple query is coming back, you may want to consider a more extensible solution. My guess, limit the autocomplete to only after the first 3 characters have been entered and make sure the searched column in MySQL is indexed. Again, more info. Update your question.

Comment: @Editor your code is vulnerable to sql injection. And how many records are in location table?

Comment: @Vyktor How can I get protection? Since beginning of record by about ten thousand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you should get rid of SQL injection, that's what are [escaping functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) for (there are some good examples on mentioned page) or you can use [placeholders in PDO expressions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) (take a look at examples again).

About speed, you've mentioned about 1000 records in one of your comments. This really shouldn't be problem for mysql database (even with terrible table design). So I assume you have slow database server (shared among many websites, overloaded, remote connect with slow connection). This can be fixed by implementing cache in php. Store data in text file, or directly in php file which would look like: `<?php return array( ...); ?>` (this is actually ugly solution, but it's the simplest, google for [`php cache`](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=php%20cache) to get more relevant results).

The second possible issue is slow connection between user and your server (your server or user has low bandwidth, long latency or so). This can be fixed probably only by loading `.js` file which would contain all the cities for example in [JSON](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.json.php) format. *This solution is suitable only for few hundreds, maybe thousands records, I wouldn't go past 5KB file.*

And finally. Let's assume you have half a million records in your table and you're query takes so long because of data amount. First step towards fixing performance would be changing `%$q%` to `$q%` (this requires user to write correctly first letter(s), not just any letter).

The second step would be to require user to type (let's say) 3 characters before loading autocomplete. Third step would take advantage of first two steps and seriously increase performance of your request. Part one: add field that would contain first three (*the number that is user required to input*) letters.

```sql
ALTER TABLE `locations` ADD `characters` CHAR(3) AFTER `city`;
```

Part 2, add index which will allow mysql access those records fast and directly:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `locations` ADD INDEX (`characters`);
```

Let's say user want's to type `Paris`. He/She types in 3 letters (par). SQL query would contain condition:

```sql
SELECT `city` FROM `locations` WHERE `characters` = '$q';
```

This should create `USING INDEX` in explain statement instead of `BROWSING ALL RECORDS` (and that's hell of performance boost, when you're having 500 000 records and only 30 begins with `par`). Of course whole query would look like (assuming `$q = substr( $qFull, 0, 3)`):

```sql
SELECT `city` FROM `locations` WHERE `characters` = '$q'
                               AND `city` LIKE '$qFull%';
```

You're almost done, but you need to update `characters` column, this can be done via:

```sql
UPDATE `locations` SET `characters` = `city`; -- Or:
INSERT INTO `locations` (`city`, `characters`) VALUES ( '$city', '$city');
```

(Don't worry, mysql will crop data automatically to fit into `CHAR(3)`)

Comment: Vyktor thank you so much! You are awesome:) I start the application.

Comment: @Editor please let us know what it really was, whether database, database-server, or server-user problem. And you're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your sql query to

```
"select city from location where city LIKE '%$q%' LIMIT 1"
```

That will improve performance a little. It may have an effect on the results though, so I'd test it on common names.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear but trying to answer it. I am not giving you a complete fix since that wouldn't develop the developers capacity at all.

Your code is very vulnerable to SQL injection, that's a first thing to take a look at. The $q is dangerous in this case. Also you don't check whether your query succeeded or not.

```
echo "$cname|$\n";
```

This is some strange code for me, what is the suggested output? Something like:

```
New York|1
```

Or do you need another result? This might be ok but my feeling says the other way around: 1|New York is more logical.

The suggested SQL:

```
select city from location where city LIKE '%$q%' LIMIT 1
```

Will leave you with a maximum of 1 result while you seem to want multiple results but every city only once, is that correct?

In file: CityAutoComp.php why do you need ob_start() and why is there that  table row code? That file should do no more than outputting the results it finds directly. Keep that very simple.

About your speed issue you should use some debugger in for example a browser to see where the delay happens. Next to that testing with: microtime() might give you concrete locations of the delays: http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php

For example put it around the query and see whether that's really the issue.

In general caching might be good for these results but it really depends on your case, it might turn out that caching isn't needed at all or all results should be realtime. That's when caching might turn out to be very expensive. So first measure before adding more complexity.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, 
+ `echo "$cname|$\n";` = "New York" ok, echo `$\n|$cname` if I only write to the print: "$"
+ I changed the call letters: `%$q%` to `$q%`
+ ob_start(): I did for the cache, how else can I do?
Automatic complementary little sped up
Database defenseless, how can I protect, What do you think?

Comment: Something like this should be fast enough: 

mm. can't get that formatting of code done :(

    require_once('database.php');

    $sql = "SELECT id, city FROM location WHERE city LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['q'])."%'";
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); //add better expection handling
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        echo $row['id'].'|'.$row['city']."\n";
    }